# How to make this <span> always the same width, regardless of whats inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, I have dynamically generated html where I assign 1-6 scaled svgs as children of a . the span is inline with 2 other spans to look like this:

[image]

I want all of these "boxes" to be the same width because they exist in a grid, however due to the varying number of svgs (sometimes there is none, sometimes 6), the  sizes differ.

What Ive tried to do is define the svg parent  width as 100px regardless, but this doesn't work. What I have:

```
var html = '<div id = "innerCal">';
html += '<div class = "calCell"><span>[</span><span style = "width 100px; display: inline-block">';
        html += svg; //varies
        html += '</span><span>]</span><h2>'+key+'</h2></div>';


#innerCal {
        position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: -17px; /* Increase/Decrease this value for cross-browser compatibility */
            overflow-y: scroll;
            text-align: center;
    }
.calCell {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.calCell > span > svg {
display: inline-block;
transform: translate(0px, 30px);
}

.calCell > h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

In the svgs I set can set width here:

```
svg += `<svg width = "20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 447 443"><defs><filter x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" id="Blur${i}"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="${gauss}" /></filter><g id="Img${i}"><path class="cls-1" d="M202.76,281.72a67.53,67.53,0,0,0,68.67-42.57,66.32,66.32,0,0,0-21.66-76.4,60.38,60.38,0,0,0-75.51,1.82c-11.79,9.87-17.32,23.53-20.44,38.24-1.69,7.94-3.74,16.27-2.77,24.42a30,30,0,0,0,10.2,18.91c12.69,11.33,32.11,19.47,49.24,18.39,15.38-1,29.86-9.82,35.21-24.65,2.17-6-7.43-8.62-9.58-2.64-3.75,10.42-15,16.68-25.63,17.35-13.55.86-27.15-4.91-38.19-12.38-5.07-3.43-9.73-8-11.11-14.15-1.48-6.69.4-13.84,1.74-20.39,2.6-12.63,6.14-24.55,15.69-33.69a50.21,50.21,0,0,1,61.73-5.74c20.3,12.94,29.65,37.62,23.84,60.86-6.89,27.54-33.4,45.3-61.43,42.68-6.36-.59-6.32,9.35,0,9.94Z"/></g></defs><use style="fill:${color};" filter="url(#Blur${i})" xlink:href="#Img${i}"transform="translate(0,0)"/><use style="fill:${fillColor};" xlink:href="#Img${i}"/></svg>`;
```

How would I do this so the boxes are always the same width? I can of course vary the width of the svgs dynamically too.
Now the svgs are stacking, despite display: inline-block

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#yourSpanElement {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you see why the svgs are stacking on top of each other now? see my edit

Comment: @skyguy I don't fully understand what is the problem :(. Can you show a sceenshot?